# sql view server state permission was denied

Tags: sql-server, permissions, system-databases

I just installed SQL server 2014 however, I have a problem creating the database or even view properties.

I get "VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on the object `'server', database 'master'. Microsoft Server, Error:300"`

I cannot alter my server roles, I have only "Public" role for some reason.
any ideas?

Comment: Did you add your account to sysadmin role while installing?

Comment: I cannot recall that I did so, is there any way that I can add my account now?

Comment: Yes you can if you are local windows admin. You should start the server in singl user mode using -m and add yourself as sysadmin. Here is a step-by-step link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for reference, this problem seems to be related to [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/791630/cannot-view-properties-of-database-when-using-db-owner-account).

I have the same problem with SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

If anyone finds stuck with this problem, try to update the SQL Server Management Studio. This way, you don't need to grant the permission VIEW SERVER STATE to the user.

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2014 (12.0.4213.0) now, and the problem seems to be gone

Comment: Mr. Rauch!  why u remove the reference link

Comment: This answer was copied from https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/141433/5203

Comment: Yes it is copied , i have also added the reference link in it but some one removed it

Comment: Nobody removed the reference link. It was formatted into the text. Copying an answer without attribution, like you did, is called [plagiarism](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Answer (score 28):

connect to ssms using administrator(sysadmin) account and execute the below

```
USE MASTER
GO
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [username]
```

Comment: After executing the code above, if the previously denied query returned **no data**, then the user running the query need to be granted the Server Role: `sysadmin`

Comment: You can also grant this by navigating in the SSMS to Security - Logins, right click on the account and display Properties - Securables. On this list you can check 'Grant' on the View Server State option.

Answer (score 3):

From [SQL Server Expert](http://www.sqlserver-expert.com/2016/02/view-server-state-permission-was-denied.html)

Login user do not have VIEW SERVER STATE permission and granting the required permission solves the issue.

```
USE MASTER
GO
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO <username>
```