# Data Migration Assistant SQL Server to Azure VIEW Server State

Tags: sql-server, azure, migration

I have a SQL Server 2012 database that I want to migrate to Azure SQL using the Data Migration Assistant v5.2.  When I get to the Select Target section, I enter a SQL Authentication account that is in the dbmanager group.  I get an error:
VIEW SERVER STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'.
The user does not have permission to perform this action.
And can go no further.
How do I get past this?

Thank you,
Dep

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql view server state permission was denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106031/sql-view-server-state-permission-was-denied)

Comment: No.  There is no VIEW SERVER STATE permission in Azure SQL.  I have no problem connecting to the database server in SSMS.  But the Data Migration Assistant is where I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

To run an assessment(DMA), you have to be a member of the SQL Server sysadmin role.

Please ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#prerequisites

There are two workarounds we could found before we migrate the on-premise SQL server to Azure SQL:

**Workaround 1:**

From the SQL Server Management Studio via statement:

1. Connect to the on-premise SQL instance
2. Select New Query
3. Use the following statement

   - `GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO "AccountName"`

**Workaround 2:**

Update your SSMS to a new version.

Comment: I must not be explaining my self well.  I have no problem on the on-premise SQL Server.  That part is not a problem.  When the DMA tool connects to the Azure SQL Server to choose the receiving database, is where I get the error.

Comment: same issue for me